# Assigning variable to input type[submit] name and using it for PHP query

Tags: php

I have the following button echo'd:

```
<input type='submit' name='delete_$id' value='x' title='Delete message' />
```

`$id` is gathered from here:

```
$get_messages = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE message_to = '$username' OR message_from='$username' AND
                DELETED ='no' ORDER BY id DESC");
  while ($get_msg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_messages)){
        $id         = $get_msg['id'];
  }
```

I want to get the id of the message the `x` is assigned to and then execute this:

```
if (@$_POST['delete_' . $id . '']){
    echo "Deleted";
}
```

But the echo is not displaying on my page, meaning the code is faulty. I have checked numerous times, and cannot figure out why it isn't working?

**Edit**:

I am simply trying to add a `delete` button which on click will `SET` the `deleted` column in my table to `yes`.

Here is the complete code where the `delete` button is found:

```
<?php
echo "
<div class='parent'> 
  <div class='msg_prof'>
    <img class='img-rounded' src='/user_data/profile_pics/$my_pro_pic'/>
  </div>
  <div class='new_msg_from_user'>
      <p><b style= 'color: red;'> You said:</b> $msg_body</p>
      <span class='faded'>$date </span>
      <input type='submit' name='delete_$id' value='x' title='Delete message' />
  </div><hr/>
</div>";
?>
```

My thinking behind this is that, I can get the id of a post using the `$id` variable, and assign that to the name. Then by using `if (@$_POST['delete_' . $id . ''])` I can perform the query based on the `$id` - for now I am trying to echo a message, just for testing purposes. This is all the code I have for this functionality.

Comment: It looks to me like you are going about this all wrong. Add some more context to your question about what you are trying to achieve. There is bound to be a better way of doing this

Comment: @RiggsFolly- I have edited my question. :)

Comment: You have to iterate through the POST array make a check on each key for a key starting with "delete_". If you find one you can access the ID using a simple string replacement.

Comment: If you do not know the `$id` when processing `$_POST` for the delete, how are you going to detect it? I dont see where you are looping over `$_POST` or doing a `preg_grep` or something else to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the php tag.

```
<input type='submit' name='delete_<?php echo $id ?>' value='x' title='Delete message' />
```

Comment: The `input` is already in an `echo` statement but I have tried it your way too, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, look what you are displaying the line:

```
<input type='submit' name='delete_$id' value='x' title='Delete message' />
```

e.g. name should/must be displayed as `name='delete_1'` or `name='delete_9'` or any other `string` having a number/digit at the end of its name. Generically said: `name='delete_anyNumber'`

For that you should have the Fetched Records of messages(those which you want to displayed and have a cross button just for a good presentation of NORMS) in PHP File and iterate through each result and in iteration-loop, echo all the messages with X buttons like:

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='delete_" . $ResultVariableHoldingRows['id'] . "' value='x' title='Delete message' />";
```

**THE REASON BEING:** (You'll have to display it correctly so that when you POST the form, you must be able to get the exact POSTED value that needs to be DELETED, so that you don't have to iterate to check which row needs to be DELETED.)

---

After you get the above problem resolved, follow below instructions:

Access the value, in PHP file that is called after Submitting:

```
    $_POST['\'delete_' . $id . '\'']
```

**SUGGESTION:** Use [AJAX-Calls](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) to DELETE the respective messages as the many forms on a single page will not be a good an approach and do some good search on AJAX before posting a question

Answer (score 0):

As in the comment mentioned you have to iterate through the `global POST array`.

```
<?php
function getRecordIdFromKey($sKey)
{
      $sId = str_replace("delete_", "", $sKey);
      $iReturn = -1;
       if (strlen($sId) > 0 && is_numeric($sId))
       {
           $iReturn = (int) $sId;
        }
        return $iReturn;
  }

  foreach ($_POST as $sKey => $mValue)
   {
          $iId = getRecordIdFromKey($sKey);
           if ($iId >= 0)
            {
                   // fire up your delete query
            }
     }
```